# Texture not getting loaded in FBX , exported using FBX SDK

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0, texture-mapping, fbx

I'm working on an OpenGLES2 project (iOS) in which I have to export a scene/model in to FBX format, so that it can be opened using FBX review app. I have made up to the point where the model getting loaded , with normals and material working fine , but texture not getting loaded. I have pasted the exported fix file and the texture file in to FBX Review app's document directory using iTunes. Following is my code:

Material creation:

```
FbxString lMaterialName = "material";
FbxString lShadingName = "Phong";
FbxDouble3 lBlack(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
FbxDouble3 lRed(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
FbxDouble3 lDiffuseColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
gMaterial = FbxSurfacePhong::Create(pScene, lMaterialName.Buffer());
gMaterial->Emissive.Set(lBlack);
gMaterial->Ambient.Set(lRed);
gMaterial->Diffuse.Set(lDiffuseColor);
gMaterial->TransparencyFactor.Set(40.5);
gMaterial->ShadingModel.Set(lShadingName);
gMaterial->Shininess.Set(0.5);
```

Texture Creation:

```
gTexture = FbxFileTexture::Create(pScene, "Diffuse Texture");
gTexture->SetFileName("sample.png");
gTexture->SetTextureUse(FbxTexture::eStandard);
gTexture->SetMappingType(FbxTexture::eUV);
gTexture->SetMaterialUse(FbxFileTexture::eModelMaterial);
gTexture->SetSwapUV(false);
gTexture->SetTranslation(0.0, 0.0);
gTexture->SetScale(1.0, 1.0);
gTexture->SetRotation(0.0, 0.0);
```

Creating FBXLayeredTexture:

```
finalNode->AddMaterial(gMaterial);
FbxLayeredTexture* layeredTexture = FbxLayeredTexture::Create(fbxManager, "layered texture");
layeredTexture->ConnectSrcObject(gTexture);
layeredTexture->SetMappingType(FbxTexture::eUV);
FbxSurfacePhong* surfMaterial = (FbxSurfacePhong*)sampleNode->GetMaterial(0);
surfMaterial->Diffuse.ConnectSrcObject(layeredTexture);

// Creating FBXLayerElementUV in another method
....
fbxMesh->InitControlPoints(objMesh->getVerticesCount());

FbxLayer* meshLayer = fbxMesh->GetLayer(0);
FbxLayerElementUV* lUVElement1 = FbxLayerElementUV::Create(fbxMesh, "UVSet1");
lUVElement1->SetMappingMode(FbxGeometryElement::eByControlPoint);
lUVElement1->SetReferenceMode(FbxGeometryElement::eDirect);
lUVElement1->GetDirectArray().SetCount(objMesh->getVerticesCount());

for (int index = 0; index < objMesh->getVerticesCount(); index++) {
    vertexData* vData = objMesh->getVertexByIndex(index);
    Vector3 vPos = vData->vertPosition;
    Vector3 vNor = vData->vertNormal;
    Vector2 vUV = vData->texCoord1;

    fbxMesh->SetControlPointAt(fbxsdk_2015_1::FbxVector4(vPos.x, vPos.y, vPos.z), fbxsdk_2015_1::FbxVector4(vNor.x, vNor.y, vNor.z), index);
    //fbxMesh->AddTextureUV(FbxVector2(vUV.x, vUV.y)); // For Trial
    lUVElement1->GetDirectArray().Add(FbxVector2(vUV.x, vUV.y));
}
meshLayer->SetUVs(lUVElement1);
// And Finally 
   ...
    finalNode->SetNodeAttribute(fbxMesh);
    finalNode->SetShadingMode(FbxNode::eTextureShading);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In this line, you should change "fbxManager" to "pScene":

```
FbxLayeredTexture* layeredTexture = FbxLayeredTexture::Create(fbxManager, "layered texture");
```

Comment: is there an explanation to this behavior? why is it not valid to create a texture with reference to memory manager? I would have spent ages debugging if not this answer